# Windows 8/IE10 Not working with $.ajax Get

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So work is upgrading all machines over to windows 8 and we have come across a compatablility issue. This works fine in all browsers except windows 8.

All these scripts are running of a windows server 2008 so I can seee why IE10 should have issues:

```
function getProject(type, number){

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                url: "prospect.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus){
                            if (textStatus!='success') {
                                $('#column-left').hide()
                                $('#column-right').hide()
                                $('#error').html('There was an error loading the data, please contact Systems Management').show()
                            }
                        },
                success: function (data) {                      
                        if (type=='all') {                          
                            parseXmlAllProjects(data)
                        } else if (type='specific') {
                            parseXmlSpecificProject(data, number)
                        }
                    }
              });             

        }
```

The script is failing at checking textStatus for some reason it is not loading the xml file successfully. Like this is running perfectly fine on our winxp environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: i am not sure the OS is your problem, since JQuery on Windows 8 and IE10 works just fine for me. On first glimpse I couldn't find an error in your statement either, maybe something else is the problem?

Comment: Try error logging in ajax error function

Comment: yeh I have tested a lot of other apps that use jquery even a similar jquery to the above and they all work fine..its got me stuffed

Comment: Just to check something - if you stick the browser into compatibility mode (to IE9 say) does it work?

Comment: I checked compatibility. IE9 doesn't work IE10 doesn't work but IE8 and below all work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some articles I found out that since IE9 IE does not return a msxml-document as previous versions of IE did. Hence the code has been changed to the below:

function getProject(type, number){

```
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                url: "prospect.xml",
                dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml", 
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
                   try {xhr.responseType = "msxml-document";} catch(err){}
                   },

                                    success: function (data) {      
                        if (type=='all') {                          
                            parseXmlAllProjects(data)
                        } else if (type='specific') {
                            parseXmlSpecificProject(data, number)
                        }
                    }
              });                           
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus){
```

To this:

```
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
```

I'm guessing IE10 doesn't like you using the `XMLHttpRequest` name.

Comment: I did the change with no effect.